# How to prevent tkinter from generating duplicating windows

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am using TKInter to create a window that display some information, something like a notice. The window should show up when the 'View Details" button of the main application is clicked.

Here is the code of the window i was talking about. The Categories() method is called when the above mentioned button is clickd.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def Categories():


    roots = Tk()
    roots.minsize(600, 600)
    roots.title("Category Details")



    labelFrameCategory = ttk.LabelFrame(roots,text="Financial")
    labelFrameCategory.configure()
    labelFrameCategory.grid(column=0 ,row=0, pady=10, padx = 30 , sticky = W)


    labelClass = Label(labelFrameCategory, text="Documents related to finance")
    labelClass.grid(column=0, row=1)
    labelClass.config(font=("Courier", 15))

    roots.resizable(False, False)
    roots.mainloop()
```

The problem I have is every time I press the button, it creates a new window but leaves the current window open. So If I click 10 times, it will open 10 similar windows. But I want it to open only 1 window no matter how many times the button is clicked, there should be only 1 such window. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your function `Categories` is invoked from a button command of another `Tk` instance. Generally you want to avoid creating more than 1 instance of `Tk`.

For your question, there are many ways to do it. One way is to simply disable your button command upon click, and re-activate the command upon the window destroy:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def new_window():
    a.config(command="")
    roots = tk.Toplevel() #Use Toplevel instead if you simply want another window
    roots.minsize(600, 600)
    roots.title("Category Details")

    labelFrameCategory = ttk.LabelFrame(roots,text="Financial")
    labelFrameCategory.configure()
    labelFrameCategory.grid(column=0 ,row=0, pady=10, padx = 30 , sticky = tk.W)

    labelClass = tk.Label(labelFrameCategory, text="Documents related to finance")
    labelClass.grid(column=0, row=1)
    labelClass.config(font=("Courier", 15))

    roots.resizable(False, False)

    def quit_window():
        a.config(command=new_window)
        roots.destroy()

    roots.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",quit_window)

a = tk.Button(root,text="Click to open new win",command=new_window)
a.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Alternatively you can also set a flag like `window_open=True` and check for the flag.

Answer (score 0):

instead of disabling the button,

why don’t you use the property name  of the toplevel?

this will allow you to use a single instance of your toplevel.

try the code below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def new_window():
    #a.config(command="")
    #use instead name='something'
    roots = tk.Toplevel(name='goofy') #Use Toplevel instead if you simply want another window
    roots.minsize(600, 600)
    roots.title("Category Details")

    labelFrameCategory = ttk.LabelFrame(roots,text="Financial")
    labelFrameCategory.configure()
    labelFrameCategory.grid(column=0 ,row=0, pady=10, padx = 30 , sticky = tk.W)

    labelClass = tk.Label(labelFrameCategory, text="Documents related to finance")
    labelClass.grid(column=0, row=1)
    labelClass.config(font=("Courier", 15))

    roots.resizable(False, False)

    def quit_window():
        a.config(command=new_window)
        roots.destroy()

    roots.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",quit_window)

a = tk.Button(root,text="Click to open new win",command=new_window)
a.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Because if you click the button 2nd time, the function is executed again and any existing input/result generated on your Toplevel will be lost. Try put an Entry field, type something and see.